# Pass 'this' reference to Backbone function

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, handlebars.js

I am trying to build a Backbone application with require.js, AMD and handlebars for template.
Here is the code for my index view.

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'handlebars',
  'collection/questions',
  'helpers'
], function($, _, Backbone, Handlebars, QuestionsCollection, Helpers){
// Main Index View
var IndexView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: "#content",
    template: Helpers.template('index'),

    initialize: function(){
        this.questions = new QuestionsCollection();
        this.questions.on('sync', this.render, this);
        this.questions.fetch();
    },

    render: function(){
        this.$el.html(this.template(this));
        this.questions.each(this.addQuestion, this);
        return this;
    },

    addQuestion: function(question){
        var view = new IndexView.Question({ model: question });
        view.render();
    },

    count: function(){
        console.log(this);
        return this.questions.length;
    }
});

// Individual Question View
IndexView.Question = Backbone.View.extend({
    render: function(){
        // console.log(this.model);
    }
});

return IndexView;
});
```

Here everything is working as expacted. But now I want to have a helper function count that will return the number of models in the collection. That way I can use `{{count}}` in my `handle bar template` to print the something like. `'There are 8 questions'`. But I am having problem with scope.

Inside `count` function this refers to the `window` but not to the `collection`. How will I be able to get reference to this inside `count` as `question collection`. I am planning to use many of those helper functions in my app. So need some solid way to do it.

THanks.

Comment: Why are you passing the view to the template function? Why not give the template function the view's data (i.e. the collection) so that you don't even need a helper?

Comment: Another option is to put the count function to the collection and refer to it as this.collection.count().

Comment: @DennisRongo But how would you use that in the template?? I want to use it in template like `{count}`.

Comment: @muistooshort I didn't really get what you mean. If I pass the collection to the template function how would that be useful? THanks.

Comment: The usual approach is to say something like `this.template({ collection: this.collection.toJSON() })`, then you have a simple array in `{{collection}}` in the template and you can ask it how long it is without worry about method binding.

Comment: You can pass your collection and your count as one object into your template. For instance, this.template{ coll: this.collection, count: this.collection.count()}. The reason I suggested the count to be in the collection is that, it frees the view from having that specific collection. This makes your view flexible and re-usable for different collections.

Comment: @DennisRongo I will try this once I get back home tonight. I guess its better that what I am doing at the moment. And I dont need to bind it as well.

Comment: @muistooshort Thanks for suggestion. I think your suggestion will work. Seems like your and DennisRongo's suggestion is prety much same. Thanks a lot guys. I will try that once I get back home snd let you know how it goes.

Comment: Guys, I tried it. Works like charm. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a '[bindAll](http://underscorejs.org/#bindAll)' function from Underscore.js as follows:

```
initialize: function () {
    _.bindAll(this, 'count');
    // your initialize code
}
```

Basically, it replaces your 'count' method with a code similar to following:

```
var thisReference = this;
var originalCount = this.count;

this.count = function () {
    originalCount.apply(thisReference, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
};
```

I.e., it just saving the original 'this' reference, and passing it when the 'count' method is called.

Today browsers have built-in support for this idiom (see  [`Function.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)).

Nevertheless, in this case it'd be better to pass the `count` as a template variable:

```
render: function () {
    this.template({
        count: this.count()
    });
}
```